# How to insert Multiple collections using .forEach() and check if it exist or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, exists

I want to insert multiple user details using `.forEach()` into my Mongodb Database.
Before insert records I want to check whether user record is exist or not. If user is not exist then insert new User record otherwise update the existing user record.

Below is

```
var dataArray=[
        {"id":"1","name":"abc","email":"abc@gmail.com"},
        {"id":"2","name":"xyz","email":"xyz@gmail.com"},
        {"id":"1","name":"abc","email":"abc@gmail.com"},
         ];

dataArray.forEach(function(dataVar){

//check record exist or not

User.findOne({id:dataVar.id},function(err,user){
    if(!user){// Insert If user not exist
        var userSchema=new User({
            id:dataVar.id,
            name:dataVar.name,
            email:dataVar.email
        });
        userSchema.save(function(err,result){
        console.log('New Record Inserted');     
        })
    }else{ // Update records if user exist
        User.update({id:dateVar.id},{email:dataVar.email},function(err,result){
        console.log('Record Updated');;     
        }); 
    }
})
});
```

When run this code snippet, its checking only first object from array and insert in my DB. But next time when 3rd object going to execute then its not checking and inserting like a new record.

I am not getting whats going on.

Please let me know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing async with sync operations in your array iteration using `forEach`. You need to iterate asynchronously. Checkout the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, it's made for control flow (async stuff) and it has a lot of methods for array stuff. You probably need `async.forEach(arr, iterator, callback)` method here.

Comment: Yeah now its working with `async`. ..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do your loop async

See: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfSeries

Example code

```
var dataArray = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
}, ];

async.eachOfSeries(dataArray, function(dataVar, key, callback) {
    User.findOne({
        id: dataVar.id
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) { // Insert If user not exist
            var userSchema = new User({
                id: dataVar.id,
                name: dataVar.name,
                email: dataVar.email
            });
            userSchema.save(function(err, result) {
                console.log('New Record Inserted');
                callback();
            })
        } else { // Update records if user exist
            User.update({
                id: dateVar.id
            }, {
                email: dataVar.email
            }, function(err, result) {
                console.log('Record Updated');;
                callback();
            });
        }
    })
}, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err.message);
    // configs is now a map of JSON data
    console.log("All done")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Now its working....... One thing I want to know, If I have 5k+ objects in my array then it will be good to use?

Comment: This should work, but maybe you can pre-process your array so you end up with an array where each object has an unique ID. (So iterate over the array, create a new one (or maybe a key-value object), and apply each 'update' to the object) This way you should have a lot less db/async actions.